# How to install an app on the system ROM as system app without rooting phone?

Tags: java, android, linux-kernel, root

I'm about to code an app which will help improving security of the device. I wanted to know is there a way to install an app as system app without rooting the device.

Like are there any special commands which can be used from inside the app to mount it in system apps.

Answer (score 2):

> I wanted to know is there a way to install an app as system app without rooting the device.
>
> Like are there any special commands which can be used from inside the app to mount it in system apps.

No, for blindlingly obvious security reasons. If any app could make itself be a system app, there would be no point in having a distinction between regular apps and system apps.